# Unable to change the customer group in magento2

Tags: magento2, customer, magento2.3, customer-group

I created the customer at time group is assigned correctly. but after login into admin I try to change the group, it is not changing but message is coming like 'You saved the customer'. 
Customer group is not changing. Anyone please help me.

Comment: do you done it programmatically?

Comment: Did you try reindex?

Comment: magento version ???

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes you can't change customer group in the adminhtml because you need to check the box just below the Group drop down, the checkbox that says "Disable Automatic Group Change Based on VAT ID". Just checkt that box, change customer group, save the customer and (if you want) uncheck the box again.